# Does rspec memoize the `subject` block?

Tags: rspec, subject, behaviorsubject

The coding standard that I'm working in specifies that a group of specs testing a function should have a subject that is the function being called. It looks like this:

```
define User do
  context :foo do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    subject { user.foo }
    it { ... }
  end
end
```

The typical use of the `subject` block is to instantiate the Class that you are testing:

```
define User do
  subject { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  it { ... }
end
```

The intended effect of our style guide is that we have a different subject block for each method that is being tested. Is this slowing down our tests? If we used `subject` in the typical manner, would we benefit from built in memoization or other speedups from only having one subject block per Class?

Asside:

I've run into one case where our style does not work. When using `any_instance.should_receive` you cannot follow our style guide or the spec will always fail. Instead, you need to use a more traditional approach where `subject` is the object that you are testing and you call the method on it in your spec.

```
# passing spec
define Foo do
  before { Bar.any_instance.stub(:baz) }
  subject { FactoryGirl.create(:foo) }
  it "bazzes Bars" do
    Bar.any_instance.should_receive(:baz)
    subject.baz_the_bars
  end
end

# spec follows style guide but fails
define Foo do
  before { Bar.any_instance.stub(:baz) }
  let(:foo) { FactoryGirl.create(:foo) }
  subject { foo.baz_the_bars }

  it "bazzes Bars" do
    Bar.any_instance.should_receive(:baz)
    subject
  end
end

class Foo
  has_many :bars

  def baz_the_bars
    bars.collect do |bar|
      bar.baz
    end.count(true)
  end
end
```

Are there any other gotcha's I should look out for with this style?

Comment: I might be missing something, why does your stubbing of Bar cause problems? The subject isn't called into existence yet, so the assertion should still be set before the method runs.

Comment: In the `before` block, I'm not stubbing `Bar`. I'm stubbing the method, `baz()`, on any instance of `Bar`. My first pass was: `before { Bar.stub(:baz) }` which also worked. But, that didn't get past code review so I needed to modify the `before` block.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - I did mean stubbing `baz` on all the `Bar`s. However, I still don't understand why your test fails. Could you update your example to be runnable? `define` isn't a valid keyword here, and I think you can drop out references to ActiveModel and FactoryGirl. Perhaps that will make the question more answerable, as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`subject` is lazily created, per-test, and scoped to the `context` / `describe`, just like `let`. There shouldn't be any extra overhead to them.

I don't personally like the style you show, but I've done something similar when I have very complicated (or just big) data objects that are returned from a method.

```
describe "A thing" do
  subject(:foo) { FactoryGirl.create(:foo) }

  # A very complicated object from this method
  describe "the result of calling frob" do
    subject(:result) { foo.frob }

    it { should be_active }
    it { should be_alive }
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. I was not asking if there was extra overhead to using `subject`. I was asking if there was extra overhead to _not_ using the same subject everywhere you could. Basically, is there some memoization that subject does which we are not taking advantage of. I'll edit the question to try to clarify. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well, I inadvertently answered that question too - `subject` is memoized during one test, but it is *per-test*, so it gets reset each time. You could have thousands of `subject` blocks (which would be a bad idea ^_^), and the only extra time would be for parsing the file.

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know. We do have thousands of `subject` blocks. Nobody's ever asked me if it's a bad idea but it's how things get done. As long as the team is on the same page, I don't care much that we do things differently from everyone else. At least that's what I try to tell myself :)

Comment: "Does rspec memoize the `subject` block?" YES, per test. is the takeaway here.